# How to print html code tags in a specific element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, replace, highlight.js

```
<div class="container">
    <pre>
        <code class="language-html">
            <h1>I want to display html tag</h1>
        </code>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-html">
            <h2>I also want to display html tag</h2>
        </code>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-not-html">
            <b>I dont want to display html tag</b>
        </code>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-css">
            html{
                margin:20x;
            }
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

I need help on how to display my html tags in plain text inside div class="container" but only to code class="language-html" using javascript or jquery. I know that changing tags into &lt and &gt but i dont know how to do it using javascript. I dont want to hard code it also because the purpose of my website is to have textfield and a button that everytime i press the button it will make a new `<pre>` and `<code>` tags. I want to make a website with a highlight.js BTW. Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually this is done when the page is generated. Not after it has already been parsed. (This is especially important when the script can be altered by users. Otherwise you're vulnerable to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).)

Comment: Please see [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68019242/295783) for a complete solution

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of Highlight.js.*

All the answers here are dangerous in that they potentially expose you to XSS and code injection attacks.  This type of encoding must be done on the server before the code hits the browser or you're just going to shoot yourself in the foot eventually when the code actually RUNS instead of just being displayed.

Having examples like this to promote this type of insecure behavior isn't good for the broader ecosystem.

The correct way to write this HTML is in escaped form:

```xml
<div class="container">
    <pre>
        <code class="language-html">
            &lt;h1&gt;I want to display html tag&lt;/h1&gt;
        </code>
    </pre>
```

Update: The code needs to be sent from the web server this way.  You cannot run JavaScript code on the client-side to "fix" this before Highlight.js sees it.  That will make the warning go away, but it will NOT fix the serious security issue.

Comment: **You can not run JavaScript code to fix this security issue on the client-side, it's impossible.**. The escaping MUST happen on the server-side before the HTML is even sent over the wire to the client.  Once it's gotten to the client it's too late - any code  injected have already run BEFORE your tiny code snippet has a change to "fix" it... _The console warning is just alerting someone to the problem._  Just making the console warning go away does NOT guarantee you have fixed the security issue.

Comment: @mplungjan Try it yourself example locally with some "malicious" code in a code block such as: `<script>alert("your owned!!!")</script>`... see if you can prevent the code from running with your snippet - you can't.  _That is the problem._

Comment: Of course you need to sanitise on the server

Comment: Yet your answer does not mention this and includes only client-side DOM code, hence the reason I spoke up.  Your approach is VERY dangerous and shouldn't be encouraged to those who don't fully understand the security implications.

Answer (score -1):

First detect `<` and `>` then use `replaceAll` to replace them to `&lt` and `&gt`

```js
var lang_html = document.getElementById("language-html");
            var innerhtml = lang_html.innerHTML
            if(innerhtml.includes("<")){
                innerhtml = innerhtml.replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
                lang_html.innerHTML = innerhtml
            }
            else if(innerhtml.includes(">")){
                innerhtml = innerhtml.replaceAll(">", "&gt;")
                lang_html.innerHTML = innerhtml
            }
```

```html
<div id="language-html">
        <a href="www.google.com">shlok jain</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: That is not enough. I already have this as part of my answer

Answer (score -2):

**Edit:** I did not originally check the tags in your question. No where did you actually mention the use of [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) in your post. I updated my response to reflect this.

I used Lodash's [_.escape](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#escape) function to convert the literal HTML to HTML text during pre-processing.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const removeTextNodes = el =>
  [...el.childNodes].forEach(child => child.nodeType !== 1 && el.removeChild(child))

const format = (text, language) => {
  switch (language) {
    case 'html': return html_beautify(text);
    case 'css': return css_beautify(text);
    case 'js': return js_beautify(text);
    default: return text;
  }
}

const preProcess = code => {
  removeTextNodes(code.closest('pre'));
  const language = [...code.classList].find(cls => /language-/.test(cls));
  const [ match, lang ] = language?.match(/language-(\w+)/);
  const content = code.innerHTML.trim();
  code.innerHTML = format(lang === 'html' ? _.escape(content) : content, lang);
};

const insertCode = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const content = e.target.elements.content.value.trim();
  const language = e.target.elements.language.value;
  if (content) {
    const formatted = format(content, language);
    const pre = document.createElement('pre');
    const code = document.createElement('code');
    code.classList.add(`language-${language}`, 'hljs');
    code.innerHTML = hljs.highlight(formatted, { language }).value;
    pre.append(code);
    container.prepend(pre);
  }
}

document.forms['add'].addEventListener('submit', insertCode);
document.querySelectorAll('code[class^="language-"]').forEach(preProcess);
hljs.highlightAll();
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  color: #EEE;
}

textarea, select {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

textarea {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  border: #DDD;
  background: #378ad3;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10em;
}

button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #3CA4FF;
}

form[name="add"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  flex: 1;
}

form[name="add"] * {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.14.0/beautify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.14.0/beautify-css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.14.0/beautify-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.0.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.0.1/styles/a11y-dark.min.css" />
<div class="form-container">
  <form name="add">
    <textarea name="content" rows="3"><h1>Hello World</h1></textarea>
    <select name="language">
      <option value="html">HTML</option>
      <option value="js">JavaScript</option>
      <option value="css">CSS</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Prepend Snippet</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <pre>
    <code class="language-html">
      <h1>I want to display html tag</h1>
    </code>
  </pre>
  <pre>
    <code class="language-html">
      <h2>I also want to display html tag</h2>
    </code>
  </pre>
  <pre>
    <code class="nohighlight">
      <b>I dont want to display html tag</b>
    </code>
  </pre>
  <pre>
    <code class="language-css">
      html{
        margin:20x;
      }
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet works perfectly here, why when i copy paste it on my VS Code my html tags still wont work? Is there any problem? Im using microsoft edge as my browser

Comment: Wow this is awesome. Thanks. Can you give some block of codes to add if i want to add a new language? like c#? no need to update the whole code above. Just some bunch of codes to insert if i wanna add new language. Thanks